# WE, US, or something else in a navigation menu

Tags: navigation, call-to-action

I've seen a lot of "About Us" item in the nav section of almost every comercial site, but wonder what can be used instead. I realize that I can shorten a bit to get something like **"US"**, but recently was wonder if I could possible change the word to **"WE"**, I want to know if it makes sense or should I try another thing like "the business name" or something catchy and fancy.

Comment: My first question would be _why_ do you want to change from "_About us_"? If the label is "too long", you may be trying to cram too much onto the page, and a deeper rethink is needed; if it's because everyone else does that and you want to be different, I would say breaking user expectations just to be _avant garde_ is _probably_ the wrong thing to do for most sites.

Comment: I've seen plenty of examples of both "About Us" and "About CompanyName". Realistically, the only way to sort this out is to figure out the KPIs for that link and then test both examples with your users - As you can probably see from the answers below, there is no way we can possibly offer you anything more concrete than opinion.

Comment: Thank you to both. In fact I have a small navigator menu, basically one word for each item. **store, freebies, blog**, and **about us**, but was thinking that just **about** fits very well there. Thank you for your observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach it with: 
 
Who = about us 
 
What = services or products 
 
 
Then additionaly if you need Why, Where or other..

Comment: I like the suggestion, it will be useful for an other project.

Comment: I ended using **WHY** to talk about we and why we serve. And **HOW** to talk about the way we do. Thank you for your advice!.

Answer (score 2):

**About us** is the conventional way to call this item, it will be the easiest one for your users to quickly understand without effort (don't make me think), if you need a shorter word, I would go with **About**, which is also a convention in a lot of websites.

**US**, might be misleading to refer to the united states, and **WE** is just not conventional, people will need a sec to figure it out and you don't want that to happen.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I think I will go for **about**. It will be like this: **store, freebies, blog, about** Let me know what you think :)

Comment: Sounds good!
don't forget to mark my answer as the answer to the question if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

"We" is perfectly fine to use, but it could be confusing when left on its own. I would suggest using naming like "We are", "We do" and so on. This makes it both short, clear and consistent in usage.